# Is it possible to select from a table without full table name?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a couple tables which uses same name pattern such as:

```
my_1_some_table
my_2_some_other_table
my_3_and_another
```

Can I query these tables only with `my_1_` ?

Thanks in advance for any tip...

**Edit:**

I think I wasn't clear enough. I just want to query a table like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_1_some_table;
```

But without using the full name. For example something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_1%
```

Comment: Do you mean querying multiple tables as one, or just using part of the name as it is still uniqe? For the first one, how would that work? SQL doesn't allow accessing multiple tables without specifying each one. For the second one, that is not allowed because if you added another table `my_1_` could stop being unique for a single table, so then the query would change meaning because you added a table that isn't specified in the query.

Comment: I mean querying one table only with the uniqe part. And why downvote? This an experimental question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** you cannot. You have to specify the name of the table when you are selecting the data from it. The best you can do is to create an alias for the tables but then too you need to create the unique alias name for all the tables you have.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. At least not without aliases. You can use an alias so as to reference the table easily.

For instance:

```
SELECT my_1.field, my_1.another_field, my_2.field_from_other_table
FROM my_1_some_table as my_1
JOIN my_2_some_other_table as my_2 on (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first get the tables you want using a statement:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'my_1_%';
```

Then create a query (stored in *preparedQuery*) using what you retrieved.

```
SET @myQuery = preparedQuery;
PREPARE query FROM @myQuery;
EXECUTE query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
```

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer that achieves programmatically what I want. But I was looking for something more native like wildcards. That's why I'll accept R.T.'s answer...

Answer (score 0):

As R.T. answered, you cannot - at least not directly.
One dirty trick you could use, however, if you're only interested in querying, is to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_1 AS SELECT * FROM my_1_some_table
```

And then you could query from it:

```
SELECT * FROM my_1
```

Comment: +1 I like the approach although not recommended. But dirty solution for some tricky things :P

Answer (score 0):

There is easy workaround just create a simple view with small names and then you can use those smaller view names in place of tablename....

```
Eg. 
-- create views with smaller name...
create or replace view my_1 as select * from my_1_some_table;
create or replace view my_2 as select * from my_2_some_other_table;
create or replace view my_3 as select * from my_3_and_another;

-- use these view name in your query...
select * from my_1;
select * from my_2;
select * from my_3;
```