# Is there a way to query and get data from a mysql table without including the table "name" or "view" strings in query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to know if a bad actor could create a mysql query to get data from a table without including the "table_name" or the "VIEW","SET","PREPARE" and "EXECUTE" keywords (in case he created a view or prepared a query previously) in a query. Is that possible?

The reason I want to know this, is because I enabled the general_log in a Google Cloud SQL MySQL database. This creates a lot of system maintenance logs every second from localhost. I am thinking about filtering out every query from localhost that does not include "table_name" or the "VIEW","SET","PREPARE" and "EXECUTE" keywords.

The goal is to create logs and monitor the queries regarding the table named "users" only. I am wondering if this approach would be enough to keep the all logs regarding this table data. Do you know a way that a bad actor could create a query and get data from the "users" table without using the words "users" or these "VIEW","SET","PREPARE" and "EXECUTE" keywords in his query. If he achieve this, the query would not be logged and security monitoring would be affected.

Information [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331494/is-it-possible-to-select-from-a-table-without-full-table-name) is useful.

Comment: If there already is a view on that table, then it can be used to get data from your users table without you detecting it

Comment: But the keyword "VIEW" would be in the query right? And CREATE VIEW with the name of the table would be there in the logs too.

Comment: That will be a one-off and if that view is already created before turning the logging on, then you would not know about it. Querying an existing view does not involve the word view.

Comment: You are very right! That would means I would need to add all the statements like SELECT that I want to monitor.I will do some research and modify or post the question again.

Comment: A bad actor could just turn off the query log in their own session.

Comment: That is true @BillKarwin and he could do it just for the time he needs to get the data and start the logging again. I guess the query to turn off the the logging would show in the logs or the mysql server would have to restart. Is this right?

Comment: Aha, now that I look it up, `general_log` and `slow_query_log` cannot be changed at the session level. They both must be `set global`.

Comment: Thank you for looking that up @BillKarwin! So the attacker would have to stop the general_log for the whole server. General_log works with a flag in Google Cloud SQL. I think the attacker would have a lot of access if he can change the flag and restart the mysql server. What do you think?

Comment: Google Cloud SQL does not grant `SUPER` privilege, which is required for changing global variables in MySQL. So an attacker who can inject SQL statements cannot use `SET GLOBAL` for any variable anyway.

Comment: All these questions are in a way beside the point. You should design your code to prevent SQL injection, then attackers cannot execute arbitrary SQL statements. The risk is preventable.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! For sure prevention must be done in the first place. That is another topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only direct way to retrieve data from a table is by using the `SELECT` statement. Additionally, views, stored procedures, and triggers can contain prepared `SELECT` queries referencing a table.

The possible options to retrieve data from the "users" table include:

1. `SELECT * FROM users`
2. `SELECT * FROM view_users`
3. `EXECUTE stored_procedure_users`

Triggers, although they can contain `SELECT` statements, are not activated manually.

However, it's important to note that a bad actor could potentially create a trigger that activates after specific events on the "users" table. This trigger could copy the contents of the "users" table into their own table with a different name. Subsequently, they could query this new table without explicitly mentioning "users" in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So maybe an alert could be set if a trigger is created too.